# Executing jquery window load function only until 50-60% page is loaded

Tags: jquery, load, window, preloader

Ok everything works fine with the website but the problem is that the preloading screen that runs using the following code takes too long to fade out and display the original website:

```
<script>
jQuery(window).load(function(){
jQuery('#loading').fadeOut(3000);
});
</script>
```

#loading is a css block with a gif image and black background to hide the page until it finishes loading.

The website is quite heavy because of large images (or my internet is slow) and the #loading from my css takes quite a long time to fade out which gives the impression of being stuck.

Now is there a way using jQuery window load function to fade out the loading screen when page is say 50-70% loaded and not to wait until the page is completely loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I would have done something like this (untested)

```
$(function(){

    var $images = $('body img'),
        imageCount = $images.length,
        loadedCount = 0;

    $images.load(function(){
        loadedCount++;
    }).error(function(){
        //error loading image
    });

    //progress: (loadedCount / imageCount) * 100 + '%'
    //do something at 70% here
});
```